# H2 Database - DATEDIFF not working properly

Tags: sql, database, h2, datediff

I'm trying to retrive a list of people based on their age, using H2 DB.

I'm using this query:

```
DATEDIFF('YEAR', BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_DATE)
```

However, if the BIRTHDATE is Oct-24-1981, H2 returns 36, and it should be 35. This person will turn 36 in October-24, so it seems H2 is only substracting actual year with the year of birth (2017-1981=36), and that's not accurate.

I know I could solve this using java, but it would take a lot of extra processing. Users need to search for all the people of a given age from the database. I'm using H2 version 1.4.195

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

You can create a user defined function:

```
CREATE ALIAS AGE AS '
    long calculateAge(java.sql.Date birthDate, java.sql.Date currentDate) {
        if ((birthDate != null) && (currentDate != null)) {
            return java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(birthDate.toLocalDate(), currentDate.toLocalDate());
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }   
';
```

And then just use it `select age('2001-09-20', now());`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

```
select cast(DATEDIFF(dd,'09-20-1981','09-17-2017')/365.25 as int)
```

Which will get you the age based on the number of months instead of year - seeing he's not 36 yet.

Comment: this is actually more accurate, but still, if the birthdate is Sept-20-1981, H2 will return 36 (when this person will turn 36 on Sept 20th)

Comment: I could use days instead, but still it will not be 100% accurate because of leap-years. With MySQL this function works perfectly, however, for this project I need to use H2

Comment: that didn't work either, it still gives me 36 instead of 35

Answer (score 1):

based on your idea, I came up with this that actually works:

```
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd, BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_DATE)/365.25)
```

It's not clean, but it works. Maybe in future versions of H2 this won't be necesary.

Comment: This will still give incorrect results on birthdays and for historical dates, for example `'1800-09-20', '1901-09-21'`. You are lucky that 2000 divides by 400 and was a leap year so currently alive people will only be affected on birthdays. I posted an alternative solution.